# Javascript check if BOTH fields contain text

Tags: javascript

JS:

```
function check_form(){
   var city = document.getElementById('sCity').value;
   var region = document.getElementById('sRegion').value
   if ((city != null || city !="") && (region != null || region !="")) {
       alert('You can only search with a PostCode OR a City. Please remove either the   City or PostCode.');
       return false;
    }
return true;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="get" class="nocsrf" onSubmit="return check_form()">
    <fieldset>
         <h3>City</h3>
        <div class="row" id="wor1">
            <input class="input-text" type="text" id="sCity" name="sCity" value="" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h3>Postcode</h3>
        <div class="row" id="wor2">             
            <input class="input-text" type="text" id="sRegion" name="sRegion" value="" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>

        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit">Apply</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zem57hfk/1/)

I need a way to check the two textfields above so that only **ONE** textfield can be text when the form is submitted. So if user types in a city + postcode, it will alert the user that the form can only take a postcode or a city.

I tried doing this myself but my code doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the condition to this:

```
if ((city != null && city !="") && (region != null && region !="")) {
```

Note the use of `&&` for each of the two conditions instead of `||`. This will make sure that the alert is shown when both fields are filled by the user.

Comment: Thanks this seems to resolve the issue. But I don't understand why the statement does not work with ||? Is it to do with the empty field triggering both null AND "" for each test?

Comment: `city` and `region` are empty strings. Because `||` was used, the first part of both conditions, i.e. `city != null` and `region != null` was always true and thus the entire condition was positive. You have to be sure that city is neither null nor empty string --> the use of `&&`.